# Python : ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, error-handling

I have got these code, But it gives a zero division error. I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I need your help. Thank you. :)

```
from math import sqrt

def inisialisasi():
    filename = raw_input('File will be read? ')
    return filename


def readdatafile(filename):
    datafile = open('kalibration.txt','r')
    datax = []; datay = []; datae = []; i = 0
    for row in datafile:
        i +=1
        data = row.split()
        x = float(data[0])
        datax.append(x)
        y = float(data[1])
        datay.append(y)
        e = float(data[2])
        datae.append(e)
        print 'x = %5.2f y = %5.2f e = %5.2f' % (x, y, e)

    datafile.close()
    n = i
    print 'Jumlah data = ', n
    return n, datax, datay, datae


def regresilinear(x, y, e):
    sum1=0.0; sum2=0.0; sum3=0.0; sum4=0.0; sum5=0.0
    for i in range(0, n):
        sum1=sum1+(x[i]**2/e[i]**2)
        sum2=sum2+(y[i]/e[i]**2)
        sum3=sum3+(x[i]/e[i]**2)
        sum4=sum4+(x[i]*y[i])/e[i]**2
        sum5=sum5+1/e[i]**2

    det = (sum5*sum1)-sum3**2
    #parameter a dan b
    a = ((sum1*sum2)-(sum3*sum4))/det
    b = ((sum5*sum4)-(sum3)*(sum2))/det
    #ralat
    sigmaa2 = sum1/det
    sigmab2 = sum5/det
    sigmaa = sqrt(sigmaa2)
    sigmab = sqrt(sigmab2)

    return a, b, sigmaa, sigmab

filename = inisialisasi()
n, datax, datay, datae =  readdatafile(filename) 

a, b, sigmaa, sigmab = regresilinear(datax,datay, datae) 

print 'a= %8.6f b= %8.6f sigmaa= %8.6f sigmab= %8.6f' % (a, b, sigmaa, sigmab)
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "coba6.py", line 55, in

a, b, sigmaa, sigmab = regresilinear(datax, datay, datae)

File "coba6.py", line 42, in regresilinear

a = ((sum1*sum2)-(sum3*sum4))/det

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, `det` is set equal to `0`.  Since you never explicitly prevent that from happening, a single input line like...

```
1.0 <whatever> 1.0
```

...can result in division by zero.  (The `y` value doesn't matter in this case.)  After substituting, you'll have:

```
sum1 = 0.0 + 1.0**2 / 1.0**2  # sum1 == 1.0
sum3 = 0.0 + 1.0 / 1.0**2     # sum3 == 1.0
sum5 = 0.0 + 1 / 1.0**2       # sum5 == 1.0
det = 1.0 * 1.0 - 1.0**2      # det  == 0.0
...
a = <whatever> / det  # KABOOM!
```

Actually, *no* input will also produce this error, since the `for` loop in `regresilinear` will never alter the various `sum*` variables from their default `0.0` values.

If you're *sure* your input isn't doing this, you might want to add `print` statements inside `regresilinear` to see how `det` is getting set to zero.  (Or use the `pdb` debugger, if you're familiar with it.)

PS:  It would be much easier to debug your functions if they weren't dependent on global data like `n`.  You don't even need it, since it should always equal the length of the three lists `datax`, `datay`, and `datae`.

PPS:  `readdatafile` completely ignores its `filename` parameter.  So if the hard-coded `kalibration.txt` file happens to be present but empty, you'll get the exact same `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 0):

What does your variable `e` look like? That is, what does it contain? If there's values of zero in it, you have your answer.